# Stability of beta coefficients

Tags: regression

If I have 24 temporal covariance matrices (say monthly covariance matrices computed from daily returns of all the SP500 stocks), and I compute 24 betas for variables x and y for every month for past 2 years. Then,

- What is then the best estimator of beta (e.g. equally or exponentially weighted average of these betas?
- How can I analyse the stability/variability of the individual beta as well as the estimator of the beta?
- By looking at these monthly betas can I make any conclusions of the relationship between x & y?

I would very much appreciate, if you have any standard references that clarify my concerns.

Comment: Perhaps this blog post http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2011/02/08/4-and-a-half-myths-about-beta-in-finance/ will be of some help.  The help might be to suggest that forgetting about beta would be a good move.  You don't say what you are really trying to do -- that is important information.

Comment: @PatrickBurns, thanks for the link but as you can see that the value of the beta for variable x (e.g. IBM) and y (e.g. S&P) is not stable (luckily +ve in this example but may even change the signs along with the magnitude) throughout time, I would like to find a stable beta for x and y using the betas I have for each of the 24 months.

Comment: It seems to me that you could process your sample as panel data.

Comment: I may be terribly ignorant, but what is a "beta" in this situation?